# Probability of the highest order statistic below the population median.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

What is the probability that the highest order statistic of a random sample of size n from any continuous distribution is below the median ( population median ) of that distribution.

Comment: What is the distribution?  Uniform?  Normal?  Exponential?  What?

Comment: From any continuous distribution. (Question edited)

Comment: no, we'd need to know what kind of distribution.  The median and the probability of being below it, varies.

Comment: This question is OK, nothing unclear about it. Should not be closed.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen The question is clear and totally lacking context.

Comment: Did: But somebody wanted to close for "unclear what youre asking" that was at least a bad reason.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Why declare it "OK" then? (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the maximum is less than the median, then all points in the sample have to be less than the median. A sampled point will be less than the median with probability $1 \over 2$, so if $Y$ is the maximum and $m$ is the population median, then 
$$P[Y \le m] = {\left({1} \over {2} \right) }^n$$

Comment: ... assuming the distribution is absolutely continuous, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that the highest order statistic in a sample of $n$ iid continuos random variables is below the median $m$ is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(\max\{X_i\}_n<m) & = \mathsf F_X(m)^n
\\[1ex] & = {\big(\tfrac 1 2\big)}^n & \text{by definition of the median}
\end{align}$$

Here, $F_X$ is the cumulative probability function for the distribution, and by definition of what a median is.

Comment: thank you for your time and response.

Comment: Wrong!  If the distribution is absolutely continuous, then $F_X(m)=1/2$, by definition of median.

Comment: Why not delete?